# How to select whole page and copy using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

im using the selemium to extract data .i need to select all the text and copy to the variable .but it select all the text but it not copying.any can help this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.')
element=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
all_text=element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'a')
copy=element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'c')
print copy
driver.close()
```

Comment: I do not know why you are using selenium, but most of the people are using complex solutions (such as selenium) instead of simpler ones (using urllib3 and bs4). Is getting all the elements what you need? I could help you with a simple script without selenium

Comment: @EDv What exactly do you mean by `all the text`? Entire html?

Comment: Why are you scraping wikipedia? That's going to break their ToS. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: i know about the bs4 and urllib.but i dont want to use that .i need to select all page like cntrl+a ,and copy that text into a variable @DebanjanB

Comment: Still not sure about your _usecase_ for which you want to do `cntrl+a` but if you want to _...copy the text... @Infern0 [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757547/how-to-select-whole-page-and-copy-using-selenium-python/52757790#52757790) looks just perfect to cater to your requirement. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get the text

```
element=driver.find_element_by_id("bodyContent") 
print(element.text)
```

to get the html content

```
driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.') 
content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content) 
print soup
```